# Place many circular shapes on top of imageview android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

So I'm making an game like "Spot The Difference" and while I can find the center of the difference I cant place a shape on top of it correctly. Using "Paint Code" I generated a class which helps me create the shape but there is still a problem with placement. I need to add many circular shapes over the center of the differences that were found. Here is the shape class and what I have tried so far:

```
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Path;

public class StyleKit {


    // Resizing Behavior
    public enum ResizingBehavior {
        AspectFit, //!< The content is proportionally resized to fit into the target rectangle.
        AspectFill, //!< The content is proportionally resized to completely fill the target rectangle.
        Stretch, //!< The content is stretched to match the entire target rectangle.
        Center, //!< The content is centered in the target rectangle, but it is NOT resized.
    }

    // Canvas Drawings
    // Tab

    private static class CacheForRoundImage {
        private static Paint paint = new Paint();
        private static RectF ovalRect = new RectF();
        private static Path ovalPath = new Path();
    }


    private static void drawRoundImage(Canvas canvas, RectF frame, int borderColor) {
        // General Declarations
        Paint paint = CacheForRoundImage.paint;

        // Oval
        RectF ovalRect = CacheForRoundImage.ovalRect;
        ovalRect.set(frame.left + 2f,
            frame.top + 2f,
            frame.right - 2f,
            frame.bottom - 2f);
        Path ovalPath = CacheForRoundImage.ovalPath;
        ovalPath.reset();
        ovalPath.addOval(ovalRect, Path.Direction.CW);

        paint.reset();
        paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3.5f);
        paint.setStrokeMiter(10f);
        canvas.save();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(borderColor);
        canvas.drawPath(ovalPath, paint);
        canvas.restore();
    }


    // Canvas Images
    // Tab

    public static Bitmap imageOfRoundImage(PointF imageSize, int borderColor) {
        Bitmap imageOfRoundImage = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) imageSize.x, (int) imageSize.y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(imageOfRoundImage);
        StyleKit.drawRoundImage(canvas, new RectF(0f, 0f, imageSize.x/3, imageSize.y/3), borderColor);

        return imageOfRoundImage;
    }


    // Resizing Behavior
    public static void resizingBehaviorApply(ResizingBehavior behavior, RectF rect, RectF target, RectF result) {
        if (rect.equals(target) || target == null) {
            result.set(rect);
            return;
        }

        if (behavior == ResizingBehavior.Stretch) {
            result.set(target);
            return;
        }

        float xRatio = Math.abs(target.width() / rect.width());
        float yRatio = Math.abs(target.height() / rect.height());
        float scale = 0f;

        switch (behavior) {
            case AspectFit: {
                scale = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);
                break;
            }
            case AspectFill: {
                scale = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);
                break;
            }
            case Center: {
                scale = 1f;
                break;
            }
        }

        float newWidth = Math.abs(rect.width() * scale);
        float newHeight = Math.abs(rect.height() * scale);
        result.set(target.centerX() - newWidth / 2,
            target.centerY() - newHeight / 2,
            target.centerX() + newWidth / 2,
            target.centerY() + newHeight / 2);
    }


}
```

And these are the methods for displaying the shapes:

```
 private void paintOverImage(int[] centerOfShape) {
        Bitmap firstImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.space1);
        PointF pointF = new PointF(125, 125);
        Bitmap overlayImage = StyleKit.imageOfRoundImage(pointF, Color.BLACK);
        Bitmap mergedImages = mergeImages(firstImage, overlayImage, centerOfShape);
        changedImageImv.setImageBitmap(mergedImages);
    }

    private Bitmap mergeImages(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage, int[] centerOfShape) {
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(firstImage.getWidth(), firstImage.getHeight(), firstImage.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        canvas.drawBitmap(firstImage, 0f, 0f, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(secondImage, 10, 10, null);
        return result;
    }
```

After all these lines of code nothing happens. The StyleKit class is correct, I mess something in the following methods. Also the centerOfShape table contains to values which are the coordinates that the shape should appear.

Comment: try drawable shape

Comment: I do not think that this the issue, the issue is that I mess the placement but I have been trying since yesterday so that is why I am asking now

Comment: First things first, games are not designed using views. Games are designed in GPU level.

Comment: Totally what I am not asking but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was loading all the time the original image. Here is the solution:

```
Bitmap firstImage = ((BitmapDrawable) changedImageImv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```